# Will two iOS devices reasonably agree on [NSDate date]?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm wondering how often iOS devices synchronize their clocks with a time server, what kind of clock drift they can be expected to exhibit after their synchronization, and in general whether or not I might be able to trust that two or more iOS devices in close vicinity will agree on "what time it is" assuming their Date & Time setting is on Set Automatically.

I need the iOS devices to agree on the date with a few millisecond threshold.. (<10)

From what I've read, I can't expect their values to be perfectly equal, but I'm unsure of how to test their margin of error.

Comment: I would do my own synchronization if that precision is needed.

Comment: Use [GPS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Timekeeping) if you can enforce it in your use case. "most receivers lose accuracy in the interpretation of the signals and are only accurate to 100 nanoseconds", which is well within your time constraints.

Comment: I've always assumed that the default mechanism for setting time is cell phone signal.  I don't know what the industry standard is, but I would expect it to be accurate to about a second, most of the time.  But keep in mind that your program is being "time shared" on the processor with other programs, so there could be "hiccups" in your program timing on the order of a half-second or so -- several seconds in extreme cases.

Comment: It would be useful to update your question to explain why you need such agreement between two devices. What are you trying to accomplish?